# Is it possible to get a source code of an android app installed in my phone?

Tags: android, apk

Well, I've lost a source to my project by accident but I have this app installed on my phone with ctrl+F11 from eclipse.

Now, all I can do is to compress this app to an apk and take the code out with dex2jar and resources with apktool.

But the code after decompiling is quite different and not the same I wrote.

IS there any other way to extract java code from my phone other than compress it to apk (with backup) and decompile it?

I really need that code :(

Comment: Of course not. This is why source control.

Comment: If it was in Eclipse, btw, you should be able to get it from local history, no?

Comment: you see, I added a repo with egit plugin and then decided to delete repo and it deleted the whole project ! what should I do to get from local history please?

Comment: Here is the answer. See the next Link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. The app installed in your phone is always the compiled version. While decompiling can get you the logic back, it will always be like generated code instead of the exact code you compiled.